# Why have I lost functionality and style when I add my items to a TabHost? How can I get it back?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I've recently started development in android and I'm still trying to get my head around a few concepts.

I've bee working on laying out a telephone-style keypad and I got it mostly working and looking the way I wanted, e.g.

[image]

My next step was to put everything we see here into tabs so that I could switch between multiple activities.

I used the following XML for the `TabHost`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="70.0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

and the following `TabActivity` to manage the tab logic:

```
[Activity(MainLauncher = true, Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar")]
public class TabContainer : TabActivity
{

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.TabContainerLayout);

        TabHost.TabSpec spec;     // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
        Intent intent;            // Reusable Intent for each tab

        // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
        intent = new Intent(this, typeof(KeypadActivity));
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);

        // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
        spec = TabHost.NewTabSpec("keypad");
        spec.SetIndicator("Keypad", Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.keypad_light));
        spec.SetContent(intent);
        TabHost.AddTab(spec);

        // Do the same for the other tabs
        intent = new Intent(this, typeof(LogsActivity));
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);

        spec = TabHost.NewTabSpec("logs");
        spec.SetIndicator("Logs", Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.logs_light));
        spec.SetContent(intent);
        TabHost.AddTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent(this, typeof(UnsetActivity));
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);

        spec = TabHost.NewTabSpec("unset");
        spec.SetIndicator("Unset", Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.unset_light));
        spec.SetContent(intent);
        TabHost.AddTab(spec);

        TabHost.CurrentTab = 0;
    }

}
```

While the tabs behave correctly, I've lost the functionality and style of my previous keypad, and it all now appears as follows:

[image]

Why is it that when I take the existing `KeypadActivity` and insert it into the `TabHost`, I lose the functionality and style? How can I maintain that inside the `TabHost`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem RE the service not working is that

```
public void OnServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service){}
```

never gets called. This is a known issue when trying to start a service within a `TabActivity`

To fix this, the `OnStart()` method needs to explicitly call the `BindService()` method in the application context, e.g.

```
    protected override void OnStart ()
    {
        base.OnStart ();

        var intentFilter = new IntentFilter (ServiceClass.UpdatedAction){Priority = (int)IntentFilterPriority.HighPriority};
        RegisterReceiver (_receiver, intentFilter);

        _serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection (this);

        Application.Context.BindService(_intent, _serviceConnection, Bind.AutoCreate);
        // instead of
        // BindService(_intent, _serviceConnection, Bind.AutoCreate);


        StartService(_intent);
    }
```

RE the style, I had to specify a specific style for the buttons, and apply that to each.